# WCF Data Service SaveChanges problem

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services, dataservice

I've published wcf dataservice project to IIS7 with .NET 4 installed on that server. Everything worked fine, but when i called SaveChanges from client, service returned error:

> Server Error in '/'
>   Application.
> Description: An error
>   occurred while accessing the resources
>   required to serve this request. You
>   might not have permission to view the
>   requested resources. 
>   Error
>   message 401.3: You do not have
>   permission to view this directory or
>   page using the credentials you
>   supplied (access denied due to Access
>   Control Lists). Ask the Web server's
>   administrator to give you access.

Tho everything works fine on my local Visual Studio host server. 
The permissions on directory, that contains websites seem to be correct. Cant identify the problem.

Service configuration:

```
config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding "Authenticated Users" to users with write permissions on *.svc file helps, but that's just bad solution. May be someone can suggest the better one?

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution to this?  I've just run into it and would rather not have to set individual permissions on the service.

Comment: @Col, strange, but no. Just left that solution and put security problems on server's administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the directory is shared with read and write privileges and enable anonymous access on IIS

Comment: Write privileges for what kind of user? Anonymous access on IIS is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the rights on the physical location of your web application.